# Passing arguments to Controller to a method in User Model

Tags: php, laravel

I have a route

```
Route::get('/{id}/{friend_id}','FriendController@addFriend');
```

And I want to pass the `id` and `friend_id` to `FriendController@addFriend` method, i.e

```
   public function addFriend(User $user)
    {
        $this->friends()->attach($user->id);
    }
```

I am not getting how to pass there parameter to the `FriendController` to `addFriend` method

Comment: In case you didn't know: Laravel has a manual. There even is a page about [Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   public function addFriend($id, $friend_id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        $user->friends()->attach($user->id);
    }
```

You can pass two arguments like this.

If you want to bind route and Model then you can associate only model not two.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was asking something else but .....thankyou soooo much ..... this was really helpful .....i solved it